# Passing a set of record Ids from a Stateful batch class to another batch class

Tags: batch, stateful

I have an ever-evolving set of custom rollups from Tasks to Accounts, Contacts, and Leads. When I add a new rollup to the code, sometimes I need to calculate the value for all parent records.

I've written a pair of Batch classes that should be able to do this for me. `RecalculateTaskRollupBatch` queries my entire task object (>2m records) and builds a set of one task Id for each parent Account, Lead, and Contact. My goal is to then pass this Id set to another batch class, `UpdateTaskBatch` that simply updates those ids, which will fire the trigger that calculates the rollup values on the parent records.

I've gotten `RecalculateTaskRollupBatch` to run just fine, and it chugs through >12k batches of 200 tasks in about an hour. But at the end of its run, it doesn't launch the `UpdateTasksBatch`.

I've invoked `Database.Stateful`, but is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
global class RecalculateTaskRollupBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful 
{
    global final String query;
    global final Integer batchSize;
    global static Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    global static Set<Id> tasksToUpdate = new Set<Id>();

    global RecalculateTaskRollupBatch(Integer updateBatchSize) 
    {
        batchSize = updateBatchSize;
        query = 'SELECT Id, AccountId, WhoId FROM Task'; //ALL TASKS!
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {   
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Task> scope) 
    {   
        // Only add one task per parent to tasksToUpdate
        for(Task t : scope)
        {
            if(t.AccountId != NULL && !parentIds.contains(t.AccountId))
            {
                tasksToUpdate.add(t.id);
                parentIds.add(t.AccountId);
            }
            if(t.WhoId != NULL && !parentIds.contains(t.WhoId))
            {
                if(!tasksToUpdate.contains(t.id)) tasksToUpdate.add(t.id);
                parentIds.add(t.WhoId);
            }
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {
        if(tasksToUpdate.size() > 0) 
        {
            Database.executeBatch(new UpdateTasksBatch(tasksToUpdate),batchSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the second batch class:

```
global class UpdateTasksBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    String query;
    Set<Id> tasksToUpdate;

    global UpdateTasksBatch(Set<Id> tasksPassed) {
        tasksToUpdate = tasksPassed;
        query = 'SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE Id IN :tasksToUpdate';
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Task> scope) {
        update scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        /*
        Eventually I would love to keep track of failed batches and retry them
        */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I kept on trying stuff and fixed the problem by removing the `static` modifier from my global id sets. The start of `RecalculateTaskRollupBatch` now looks like this (and it works):

```
global class RecalculateTaskRollupBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful 
{   
    global final String query;
    global final Integer batchSize;
    global Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    global Set<Id> tasksToUpdate = new Set<Id>();

    global RecalculateTaskRollupBatch(Integer updateBatchSize) 
    {   
....
```